# Log in as domain\user with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, webforms, active-directory, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider in ASP.NET WebForms app with this configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ADConnection" connectionString="LDAP://XXX/OU=XX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=ac,DC=za"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

...

```
<membership defaultProvider="ADProvider">
 <providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="ADProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnection" enableSearchMethods="true" />
 </providers>
</membership>
```

This allows me to log in using user@XXX.XXX.ac.za, but I want to log in using domain\user like one does in Windows. I can't figure out how to do this.

I know I can add attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" to the provider definition, which lets me log in simply as 'user' but that's not viable for this client because multiple domains are involved. When I try, I get an error later when I call GetAllUsers() ("Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'XXX' Key being added: 'XXX'").

Is there a way to configure ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider so I can log in with domain\user?

Comment: Are the snippets above it? Are there any other options in web.config that have to do with authentication?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "are the snippets above it", but web.config has forms authentication specified: <authentication mode="Forms"><forms name="GSP" protection="All" timeout="129600" slidingExpiration="true" /></authentication>